# Unable to start the Jmeter-Server in background in Jenkins pipeline. Getting ConnectException

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to implement distributed performance testing where I have a chance of launching multiple slave node parallelly when user count is high. Hence I suppose to launch master and slave nodes.

I have tried all the way to start jmeter-server in the background since it has to keep on running in the slave node to receive the incoming request.

But still, I am unable to start it in the background.

```
node(performance) {
    properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])
    stage('Setup') {
        cleanAndInstall()
        checkout()
    }
    max_instances_to_boot = 1
    for (val in 1..max_instances_to_boot) {
        def instance_id = val
        node_builder[instance_id] = {
            timestamps {
                node(node_label) {
                    stage('Node -> ' + instance_id + ' Launch') {
                        def ipAddr = ''
                        script {
                            ipAddr = sh(script: 'curl http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', returnStdout: true)
                            node_ipAddr.add(ipAddr)
                        }
                        cleanAndInstall()
                        checkout()
                        println "Node IP Address:"+node_ipAddr
                        dir('apache-jmeter/bin') {
                            exec_cmd = "nohup sh jmeter-server -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$ipAddr > ${env.WORKSPACE}/jmeter-server-nohup.out &"
                            println 'Server Execution Command: ' + exec_cmd
                            sh exec_cmd
                        }
                        sleep time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES'
                        sh """#!/bin/bash
                              echo "============ jmeter-server.log ============"
                              cat jmeter-server.log
                              echo "============ nohup.log ============"
                              cat jmeter-server-nohup.out
                           """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    parallel node_builder
    stage('Execution') {
        exec_cmd = "apache-jmeter/bin/jmeter -n -t /home/jenkins/workspace/release-performance-tests/test_plans/delights/fd_regression_delight.jmx -e -o /home/jenkins/workspace/release-performance-tests/Performance-Report -l /home/jenkins/workspace/release-performance-tests/JTL-FD-773.jtl -R xx.0.3.210 -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -Dclient.tries=3"
        println 'Execution Command: ' + exec_cmd
        sh exec_cmd
    }
}
```

Getting following error

```
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xx.0.3.210; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Comment: Where I tried without using ```nohub``` it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolve by adding inside the node stage.

```
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe nohup sh jmeter-server -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.xx.xx.xxx > ${env.WORKSPACE}/jmeter-server-nohup.out &
```

Answer (score 0):

We're unable to provide the answer without seeing the contents of your [nohup.out file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) which is supposed to contain your script output.

Blind shot: by default JMeter uses secure communication between the master and the slaves so you need to have a [Java Keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) to contain certificates necessary for the requests encryption. The script is [create-rmi-keystore.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/create-rmi-keystore.sh) and you need to launch and perform the configuration prior to starting the JMeter Slave.

If you don't need encrypted communication between master and slaves you can turn this feature off so you won't to create the keystore, it can be done either by adding the following command-line argument:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

like:

```
nohup jmeter-server -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true &
```

or alternatively add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)

Comment: Dmitri, This is the content available in nohub.out ```Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[xx.0.3.210:44795](local),objID:[-794e5958:175a1502d58:-7fff, 1938170908024818443]]]```